# Is there a way to add a time stamp in all file names in a folder?

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm currently using aws cli in a linux EC2 instance to move files from a folder to an s3 bucket.
I would like the files to be moved to have the current time  or even better, **the file created at date** in their name. Is that possible?
This is my command:

aws s3 mv /home/wowza/content/ s3://bucket/folder/ --recursive

It doesn't have to be an aws cli command. It can be commands that rename all the files in the folder and then I run the aws s3 command.

Comment: Probably, but since you haven't given us any details on where you're running this (e.g. OS), we can't help you.

Comment: Oh, ok sorry. it's Linux. It's an EC2 instance I'm accessing through ssh.

Comment: Why change the name when you can simply apply the appropriate metadata around the file where it belongs.

Comment: Because I need to upload them with a different name so they don't overwrite the already uploaded ones. Plus, I want the date in the name.

Comment: Is there a reason the different versions need to be in the same bucket? Why don't you create a bucket with the time in the name, then load everything into that bucket.  Seems cleaner to me.

Comment: I still prefer my first option but I like that. How can I create a bucket with the date as a name?

Comment: An entirely new bucket would be overkill. You can simply use a timestamp prefix. You can generate the timestamp with bash. `aws s3 mv /home/wowza/content/ s3://bucket/$(date +"%s")/folder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that linux doesnt record creation time but I could add the current date to all my files like this:

> for f in test/*; do mv -- "$f" "$f-$(stat -c %Y "$f" | date +%Y%m%d)";
>   done

Answer (score 1):

you could rename the files in #bash (using for) and then upload to AWS s3.

```
for f in test/*; do TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s); FILENAME=${f%.*}; EXTENSION=${f##*.}; NEWNAME="$FILENAME-$TIMESTAMP.$EXTENSION"; mv $f $NEWNAME; done
```

Comment: That only got the hour ok and then some number that didn't make sense.